# How do I put a dictionary into JSON without the escape slash

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, escaping

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  I have a dictionary that I want to convert to JSON.  My problem is with the escape \

How do I put a dictionary into JSON without the escape \

Here is my code:

```
def printJSON(dump):
    print(json.dumps(dump, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

data = {'number':7, 'second_number':44}
json_data = json.dumps(data)
printJSON(json_data)
```

The output is:
    "{\"second_number\": 44, \"number\": 7}"

I want the output to look like this:
    "{"second_number": 44, "number": 7}"

Comment: Why are you dumping the data twice? The first dump turns the data into a string, the second dump encodes the string, did you mean `printJSON(data)`?

Comment: creating a string (`json_data`) by dumping the dict -- Then you're dumping that string to JSON again inside `printJSON` -- The escapes are correct... Why are you dumping it twice?

Comment: Then you need to pass your `printJSON` function a `dict`, not a string, which is what you are currently doing.

Comment: Thanks, Scott, for including a [mcve] in your question.

Answer (score 22):

The reason is because you are dumping your JSON data twice. Once outside the function and another inside it. For reference:

```
>>> import json    
>>> data = {'number':7, 'second_number':44}

# JSON dumped once, without `\`
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"second_number": 44, "number": 7}'

# JSON dumped twice, with `\`
>>> json.dumps(json.dumps(data))
'"{\\"second_number\\": 44, \\"number\\": 7}"'
```

If you print the data dumped twice, you will see what you are getting currently, i.e:

```
>>> print json.dumps(json.dumps(data))
"{\"second_number\": 44, \"number\": 7}"
```

Comment: Yup that was the problem.  I suppose that is what to expect when hacking around

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different problem that resulted in the same issue. My code had this:

```py
requests.post('https://example.com/data', data=clinicListBody).text
```

When it should have had this

```py
requests.post('https://example.com/data', data=clinicListBody).json()
```

.text was returning a string with strings inside it, which is why I was seeing escaped json in the saved file.